# Problems with JSONObject class, no error given

Tags: java, json

I'm building a little API that I will call and receive back JSON data about the directory. Its working perfectly on my dev box running, however when I put it on the server i need it on, it gets part way through the application and just stops.

No exceptions are thrown, console outputs dont do anything and I receive no response from my GET request to the server. The plugin just stops.

This is an HTTPProvider running as a plugin on a Wowza server, but I don't think thats relevant. The server doesnt crash, my plugin just doesnt do anything after this point in the code (Each set of comments are places I tested with console output, all worked but the last one):

```
File dir = new File(appInst.getStreamStoragePath()+"/"+content_path);
//Correct Path is formed and file object created
if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory())
{
    //Directory exists
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(); 

    //Was able to find the 2 files in this directory

    JSONObject output = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray directories = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray videos = new JSONArray();
    boolean access_allowed = true;

    //Nothing happens after these declarations, no errors
    //No thrown exceptions or console output

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        //Build JSON objects+arrays with files
    }
}
```

Both dev box and server are the same versions of java and wowza server. (1.6)

My main question is not so much how to fix it but how do I even go about figuring out whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue I guess was that I did not include the org.json.* package into my application. The reason it worked (And why i thought nothing was wrong since it worked locally) is because of the way Wowza loads plugins. Another plugin already had the JSON package, but the server did not have this same plugin.

I fixed it by including the JSON package into my plugin's build path.

Its still weird to me that there were no errors at all though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging remotely?